# CasperJS continue equivalent inside for loop with casper.then

Tags: javascript, casper.js

CasperJS doesn't allow `continue` statement inside a `casper.then` functions. This was my solution but I'm not happy about it. Is there a better way to achieve this effect?

```
casper.start();
        casper.then(function() {
            var current = 1;
            var end = 4;
            var skip;

for (;current < end;) {
  (function(cntr) {
    casper.thenOpen('about:blank', function() {
          this.echo('loop number: '+ cntr);
          skip = false;
    });
    casper.then(function(){
        if (skip) {
            this.echo('skipping');
        }
        else {
            // put all code here that was in casper.then
            this.echo('proceed as normal');
            // some condition requires skipping...
            skip = true;

        }
    });

    casper.then(function(){
        if (skip) {
            this.echo('skipping');
        }
        else {
            // put all code here that was in casper.then
            this.echo('this no longer gets printed');
        }
    });
  })(current);
  current++;
}
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What is this code intended to accomplish?

Comment: @200_success the goal is to replicate what `continue` inside of a for loop would do (continue to the next loop iteration).  `continue;` inside a `casper.then` throws an error so I'm trying to find a work around.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to open `about:blank` several times? Why?

Comment: @200_success ... because this is a simplification of the code I'm actually writing where multiple sites will be iterated in place of about:blank.

Comment: Could you put in something more realistic?